# Gtk 3 python entry color

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to make a text entry with a gray hint in it that goes black when someone enters text into it. had already made a similar question but more broadly to try to get there by me, but not served as much. But anyway, it can help other problems.

My other question:
[Gtk python entry color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655829/gtk-python-entry-color)

Comment: You should not repost the same question again if its been closed previously. A better way to get an answer would be to make changes in the previous post and get it reopened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gtk+ python entry color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655829/gtk-python-entry-color)

Comment: is not the same question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different parts to this solution. Firstly the coloring is handling by the css which colors the text grey when the entry box is not focused and then black as it gains focus. The second part is up to you if you wish to implement which is that you might want to clear the grey text in the box as the text box gets focus. For convenience I have put focus in and out event handlers that currently just print to the terminal.

**code**

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def focus_in(*args):
    print 'focus_in called'

def focus_out(*args):
    print 'focus_out called'

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css_provider.load_from_path('style.css')
priority = Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER
context = Gtk.StyleContext()
context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, priority)
fname = Gtk.Entry(text='First Name')
lname = Gtk.Entry(text='Last Name')
button = Gtk.Button('Submit')
fname.connect('focus-in-event', focus_in)
fname.connect('focus-out-event', focus_out)
vbox = Gtk.VBox()
vbox.add(fname)
vbox.add(lname)
vbox.add(button)
window.add(vbox)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

**style.css**

```
GtkEntry {
    color: darkgrey;
}

GtkEntry:focused {
    color: black;
}
```

**screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please, don't use CSS or HTML when the toolkit provides a perfectly good facility for placeholder text:

```
entry.set_placeholder_text('First name')
```

Works on GTK 3.2 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Another completely different approach to solving this problem would be to take advantage of some excellent HTML5 features and the great webkit library that is available for both qt and gtk. Both qt and gtk examples of using this will be presented below. What you would like to implement is available in HTML5 as an attribute called placeholder. You can see a nice [demo of this on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder).

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" />
```

Then you implement your fields and form using HTML and webkit. There are many ways then to communicate between your html and python code. I find HTML a much easier and more documented way of creating user interfaces.

**GTK Version**

```
import gtk, webkit

HTML = """
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" /><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" /><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body></html>
"""

win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
win.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
view = webkit.WebView() 
view.load_html_string(HTML, 'file:///')
win.add(view)
win.show_all() 
gtk.main()
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**QT Version**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

HTML = """
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" /><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" /><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body></html>
"""

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QtWebKit.QWebView()
view.setHtml(HTML)
window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**sceenshot**

[image]

**Final notes**
When interacting with the interfaces you will see the `placeholder` feature in webkit is implemented in a way that feels natural and is as expected. These types of features are difficult to correct right if you decide to implement them yourself, so that's just something to be aware of.